# convert raw tweets data into PHP associative array

Tags: php, json, twitter

I have following crawled tweets data in JSON format using Twitter API:I want to store it in mysql or some other database for further processing, what should I do in order to store it in some relational database.

```
{u'iso_language_code': u'en', 
'to_user_name': None, 
'to_user_id_str': u'0', 
'profile_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1188223217/aoa-logo_normal.jpg', 
'from_user_id_str': u'225222094', 
'text': u'CoS: Live Review: Mission of Burma at Chicago\u2019s Lincoln Hall (9/29) http://t.co/cjeSqimv #axisofaudio', 
'from_user_name': u'Axis Of Audio', 
'profile_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1188223217/aoa-logo_normal.jpg', 
'id': 252638989289398273L, 
'to_user': None, 
'source': u'&lt;a href=&quot;http://dlvr.it&quot;&gt;dlvr.it&lt;/a&gt;', 
'id_str': u'252638989289398273', 
'from_user': u'axisofaudio', 
'from_user_id': 225222094, 
'to_user_id': 0, 
'geo': None, 
'created_at': u'Mon, 01 Oct 2012 05:20:03 +0000', 
'metadata': {u'result_type': u'recent'}
```

Regards

Comment: Your JSON is invalid! How do you get it? This strange 'u' is everywhere..

Answer (score 0):

To convert it into an array you can use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), quick example:

```
<?php
  $feed = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&count=10&include_rts=t";
  $feedContent = file_get_contents($feed);
  $feedContent = json_decode($feedContent, true);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($feedContent);
  echo '</pre>';
```

However, you can't just store an array in a database, so either store the json data in the database, or preferably, [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array before adding it to the database.

Comment: I'm assuming he has valid JSON somewhere, or at least, is getting valid JSON back from twitter. Probably just has had issues when he's copied the JSON from somewhere into his question.

Comment: After executing above code I got following errors:                   Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\me.php on line 3      and Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&count=10&include_rts=t) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\me.php on line 3